# Deferred getJSON's return is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

It's the first time I attempt to do a deferred function and I'm clearly getting something wrong. I got a bit confused as there's apparently several ways of doing this but I tried working from the simplest I could find

```
Get_JSON( my_url ).done(function(data) {
    console.log( data['name'] );
});

function Get_JSON( url ) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
        console.log( data['name'] );
        def.resolve({
            data:data
        });
    });
    return def;
}
```

My console output is:

```
John
undefined
```

(John being the expected name)

I suspect it's the `def.resolve` part that I'm getting wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're using the wrong key:

Do:

```
Get_JSON( my_url ).done(function(data) {
    console.log( data.data['name'] );
});
```

---

However, you can simplify your code to this:

```
Get_JSON( my_url ).done(function(data) {
    console.log( data['name'] );
});

function Get_JSON( url ) {
    return $.getJSON(url);
}
```

Or even to this:

```
$.getJSON(my_url).done(function(data) {
    console.log( data['name'] );
});
```

Basically, `$.getJSON` already returns a `Deferred` object, and your code is adding redundancy by proxying it.

Comment: Consider `console.dir(data)`, which would allow you to inspect all properties of `data`, not just `.name`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior. In your `resolve` call, you're passing an object `{data: data}` (let's called it object A), so it's an object which has a `data` key, and which value is the `data` object from the `$.getJSON(url).done` callback (let's call it object B). This last object has a `name` key, but the object you retrieve in your `Get_JSON( my_url ).done` callback is the object A (which has only a `data` key) and not the object B.

You should have write your code like this:

```
Get_JSON( my_url ).done(function(data) {
    console.log( data['name'] );
});

function Get_JSON( url ) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
        console.log( data['name'] );
        def.resolve(data); // here is the only difference
    });
    return def;
}
```

Comment: No point in continuing to create a deferred since `$.getJSON()` already returns a promise - might as well just use that one.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're absolutely right, and that's why I have upvote tcooc answer. But this was not the main point of my answer